# Setting selectedTitleTextAttributes for a UIControl subclass

Tags: swift

I'm using a segmented control library called `HMSegmentedControl`, which isn't too complex, However, setting its `titleTextAttributes` is giving me a bit of trouble.

`titleTextAttributes` is type `[AnyHashable: Any]!` via Swift. In the objc file, it's `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes`

Here's what I'm doing:

```
let segmentedControl = HMSegmentedControl(sectionTitles: ["All", "A", "B"])!
segmentedControl.titleTextAttributes = [
      NSFontAttributeName: Styleguide.Fonts.someFont.font(ofSize: 9),
      NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGray
]
```

Xcode is giving me "use of unresolved identifier" errors for `NSFontAttributeName` and `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its because those are Obj-C identifiers. You should use the Swift ones:

`NSAttributedStringKey.font` (or usually simply `.font`, swift can infer the rest when dealing with native objects, maybe not in this circumstance though if its declared as an `AnyHashable: Any`)
and `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor`.

So what you want is:

```
segmentedControl.titleTextAttributes = [
      NSAttributedStringKey.font: Styleguide.Fonts.someFont.font(ofSize: 9),
      NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray
]
```